# Recursive slugs in vue-router routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm setting up a website which will contain groups, these groups can have sub-groups and these sub-groups can have sub-groups and so on...

Is this in any way possible?

Ofcourse making the path of a route like: `/groups/:slug/:slug` does not work since it contains duplicate params.

What I was thinking of was using the star pattern as child route, this child route will redirect the user back to the parent route with the slug and a sub-slug, then the next action will be to act on the sub-slug if it exists. But maybe someone has a better solution to this?

```js
const groupRoute = {
    path: `/groups/:slug`,
    name: 'group',
    component: Group,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: GroupsHome
        },
        {
            path: '/subgroups',
            component: SubGroups
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                next({
                    name: 'group',
                    params: {
                        slug: to.params.slug,
                        subSlug: to.params.pathMatch
                    }
                })
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Must you use all of the params as slug? ``/groups/:slug/:<param-name>`` will just work fine.

Comment: Yes, the groups have slugs, so a nested group contains a slug within a slug. So I need someway to make it possible to get to the nested group, as described

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a basic example:](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-9867o)

Nested navigation with similar structure for nested objects. The trick here is to use a different param name for inner routes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if you go another layer deeper.

The subgroup is actually the group again, needs to have the GroupHome, with again links to subgroups if they exist.

Comment: Changing the param name is still sufficient. I've updated the sample to show this. If you need to load child routes inside the parents, you can still modify your route config without modifying your components - except to add an anchor point for your child routes with <router-view> element.

Comment: Yeah but that is exactly something you do not want to do, this is unmaintainable. For example, what if you have 5 nested groups? You do not want to make a path like: `':_slug/:__slug/:___slug/:____slug/:_____slug'`

Comment: You know you are in full control of that param name, right? Essentially, my choice to use the underscore wasn't a limitation, you can name it however you want, or I'm missing the point?

Comment: Probably missing the point. The groups all have slugs as described, so when the data comes from somewhere with 5 nested groups I don't want to make it as I said with 5x slugs. What if someone makes 10 nested groups for whatever reason but it can happen. Then I need to write it all out?

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you can have a url like: group-1/sub-1-group/sub-2-group/ all the way down to .../sub-<n>-group. Right?

Comment: Yes sir, maybe easier to discuss this in Discord and post the result here of what we came up with ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196000/discussion-between-murwa-and-gerdon-abbink).